# How to work in jQuery with a database?

Tags: jquery, database

I am learning `jQuery` and just found out that  can Jquery supports  database connection .

I found some  plugins here :
https://www.sitepoint.com/top-10-jquery-database-plugins/

How can I implement something like this?

Isn't Jquery only for dynamic styling ? and if jQuery can support a databases What are his limits ?

any basic tutorial about how to connect and work with a databse in jquery ?

Comment: jquery is candy; mysql/php is meat. Two different animals/food groups here.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  i want to know what can i achieve with jquery database maybe i can used i small projects before learning php , anyway i know mysql but not php , maybe i can't work with jquery and mysql until i learned php ?

Comment: If you notice the examples they still have a backend api that is actually inserting the data. Jquery is only used to ajax requests. That being said javascript can be used for connecting to some specific databases that work over http like google firebase.

Comment: jquery knows nothing about databases, it can only interact with it, in conjunction with HTML. jQuery is client-side; databases are serverside. jQuery lets you do all sorts of fun / fancy things to "pretty up" the way it's presented to the user.

Comment: @Fred-ii- what kind of interacting ? :) Like what 
store some data in browser or user side ?

Answer (score 4):

**You can use Browser Storage to store Key-Value-Pairs locally. There is no jQuery needed for this.**

1. To set a item use `localStorage.setItem("string1", "StackOverflow");`
2. To retrieve a item use `localStorage.getItem("string1");`

This has the advantage of quickly being able to store things in the browser without the need of a database, but the data is in no way secure. It can be modified by the user at any time and you can't be sure about the integrity of it. Also clearing browser data will also wipe these values.

**This should never be used to store things like passwords, credit card numbers or other important data.**

It's rather designed to allow storing of settings like theme color or other info that does not need persistence.

**Original answer:**

You are messing up server and client side.

1. jQuery is a client side Javascript framework and not a database engine. Javascript offers ways to store data in the browser but that is not secure. If you want to store things like Passwords, ... you need to send them to a server that stores it.
2. Databases are usually on the server.

To implement a database with jQuery you would need a server backend (usually a PHP script that accepts input and stores it to the database).

You can call this php script from your site with jQuery through it's [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) functionality.

Comment: you mean that data will not be stored in server with jquery ? :)

Comment: You need a server that runs a database. Since there are secret credentials that you don't want your website's visitors to see you need to use a server script. If you want to store data locally i'd suggest looking into WebStorage: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: i meant in small projects , maybe creating page that store user data localy and use it in a next step creating cv and download it maybe... no account or such thing !! 
this could be achieved with only jquery ?

Comment: @MustaphaElbazi yes, you can use Browser Local Storage which is supported natively by Javascript. jQuery is not even needed for that.